# What does "just as" mean in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can you help me to understand "just as"'s mean in this paragraph. Thank you!

> Your tone, tempo, and volume could reveal, for instance, that you are nervous and insecure, despite your confident words, **just as** it is not enough to say all the right things with perfect timing if you are speaking too fast or so quietly that people cannot even hear you

Comment: It means *exactly as*. You can find this in a dictionary.

Comment: How can you speak *with **perfect timing** if you are speaking **too fast**?*

Comment: so "as" means "because", right?

Comment: Did you check a dictionary about this? http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/just%20as

Comment: But I don't find a relation between two sentences "Your tone, tempo, and volume could reveal, for instance, that you are nervous and insecure, despite your confident words" and "just as it is not enough to say all the right things with perfect timing if you are speaking too fast or so quietly that people cannot even hear you". Can you explain more carefully for me (sorry, I'm not Native English, and my English is not good so I can't understand)

Comment: The author might see a relation even if you don't. Being grammatically correct doesn't mean the author is right.

Comment: ***Timing*** may refer to ***when*** you say something, not ***how fast*** you say it.

Comment: We are looking for long, thoughtful, intriguing questions, showing effort and research. A dictionary or thesaurus may be quite helpful. Your question should include the results of your search. It should also explain why the results were not adequate to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I don't find a relation between two sentences

The first sentence claims that it is not enough to say the right words, you must also say them in the right tone, tempo, and volume.

The second sentence claims that it is not enough to say all the right things with perfect timing, you must also say them slowly and loudly enough.

The two sentences are similar in claiming that it is not enough to do X, you must also do Y (or not do Z). This is why they are joined by ***just as***.